# The requested URL /xxx/login_public was not found on this server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to click a url for an application handed over to me to take up and continue the development. On clicking a url I get this error as a prompt

```
The requested URL /xxx/login_public was not found on this server.
```

I cannot figure out where this error is coming from

This is the code structure from the view section

```
href="<?php echo site_url()."login_public"; ?>" >Click here</a>
```

**EDITTED**

this is site_url() function

```
if ( ! function_exists('site_url'))
{
    function site_url($uri = '')
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        return $CI->config->site_url($uri);
    }
}
```

Please how can I debug this error and what does it actually stand for. I new to codeigniter.

Comment: If its a link your clicking then its your browser telling you the URL you are looking for does not exist.   Meaning the file it points to is not there.  Do you manage the server where the URL points to?  Oh, ad `site_url()` looks like a custom function that was created to return the site base URL.  Look in your code for something like `function site_url(){}`

Comment: Can I paste the function here

Comment: Just edit your original message

Comment: Have just included site_url() function

Comment: can I get rid of this custom function

Answer (score 1):

Check all of your controllers for a method called login_public. If you can't find one, it is possible that a custom route has been added to /application/config/routes.php

Comment: is there a way I can override this custom root

Comment: login_public is a name of a controller

Comment: Ok, does it have a method called index()?

Comment: Ok, when you call http://www.yourdomain.com/login_public/ the code that is served is the code in the index method of the login_public controller, provided there is no trickery going on. Check for custom routes. Check for hooks. Check for show_404(). Put a breakpoint in your main index.php file and see if that is even being hit.

Comment: Custom routes are located in /application/config/routes.php. For show_404 just do a find in all files of your project with your IDE

Comment: yeah. I can the routes.php file

Comment: Ok, can you let me know what the route is?

Comment: $route['default_controller'] = "index/get_started";
$route["validate"] = "admin/login/validate";
$route["logout"] = "admin/login/logout";
$route["chat_room/(:any)"] = "general_functions/chat_room/$i";
$route["all_users"] = "create/all_users";
$route['404_override'] = '';

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138982/discussion-between-parker-and-webcode-ie).

Comment: please can we move this to chat